# when i close my laptop lid my secund screen requiers password when set to do nothing

Tags: 14.04, suspend, laptop, power-management, hdmi

I'm new to Linux using Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS 64-bit and using a Fujitsu lifebook a series. When I close my laptop lid while trying to watch a movie on my TV with the HDMI cable. the screen requires my password like it does when waking up from suspending it. Under All settings > Power, everything is set to do nothing and don't suspend. Is there a way to fix this?

I already disabled the Lock feature in System Settings -> Brightness and Lock, but it keeps asking me anyway. When I close the lid, the TV flickers like it turns off, but turns back on very quickly. But it takes me to the password screen and since I closed the lid I can't use the keyboard.

---

Yes sorry i forgot to say that i already unchecked that funktion. But its keeps asking me any way. When I closey lid the tv flikers like it turns off but turns back on very quickly. But it takes me to the password screen and sense I closed the lid I cant use the keybord.

Answer (score 1):

You have to disable the **Lock** feature in the **Brightness and Lock** tool, otherwise it's default to lock your system when you close the lid (turn the screen off).

[image]